# How can i stop hanging page when a request is send via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am facing a serious issue... Whenever i use Ajax to send a request and get an response my browser got hanged.. and show no loading etc...

But when i response is retrieved from the Ajax then browser and page again start working...

Below is the code that i used.....

```
function ShowContestStatus(contestID)
{
    $("#showContestDetails").html('<div class="loadercontest"><img src="assets/images/loading.gif">Loading Contest....</div>');

    $("#RadioGroup1_0, #RadioGroup1_1, #RadioGroup1_2").prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
            url:"process/processMyContest.php",
            type:'POST',
            cache:false,
            async:false,
            data : {act : 'showcontest', cid : contestID },
            success:function(result)
            { 
                $("#showContestDetails").html(result);
                $("#RadioGroup1_0, #RadioGroup1_1, #RadioGroup1_2").prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me on this... i want to get the same response as on other websites when you send a request and they are using ajax the page neither hanged and also each processing like scrolling etc is visible ......

So please suggest me good ideas....  so i can get rid of it and make my ajax smooth for page without effecting and irritate the other person by hanged...

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: In the browser console do you see any error?  If there is can you also include that

Comment: `async:` is set to false, use `true`, thats the logic of using ajax, so that your request is asynchronous

Comment: @andrex Code works properly and also give success one all the request done.. but when i call this function the page hanged.. that's the main issue..

Comment: the request should be asynchronous to avoid hanging. so make `async: true` or just remove that field.

Comment: @Ghost So this will help to stop page being hanged and show loading icon while request is not properly completed???

Comment: Okay i will check it.... but is there any more parameters for ajax that i can use for more smooth calling of ajax ...?? or this is all that i used..?

Comment: @DeDevelopers just reenable the buttons after you done, thats just it, check out arun's answer

Comment: I do this now and it is working but after sometime again page looks like it hanged in chrome.. but firefox is giving no such issue.. can we overcome this thing with any code if possible? –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `async:false`... Since your ajax request is synchronous the script execution will wait for the request to complete to continue..

Since browser uses a single threaded execution pattern(either it will execute script or repaint or wait for user events at a time- not all at the same time), your browser tab will stop listening to user(so it will look like it is hanged)

```
function ShowContestStatus(contestID) {
    $("#showContestDetails").html('<div class="loadercontest"><img src="assets/images/loading.gif">Loading Contest....</div>');

    $("#RadioGroup1_0, #RadioGroup1_1, #RadioGroup1_2").prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        url: "process/processMyContest.php",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        //remove async: false,
        data: {
            act: 'showcontest',
            cid: contestID
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#showContestDetails").html(result);
            $("#RadioGroup1_0, #RadioGroup1_1, #RadioGroup1_2").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
}
```

[Ajax.async](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. **Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active**. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR
>   ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete
>   callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR
>   object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Comment: and it is depreciated As of jQuery 1.8

Comment: Okay Thank you Arun... I will surly apply this method..i checked this code from many places and they used false, so i just used that.. well thanks for such information...:)

Comment: @Arun I do this now and it is working but after sometime again page looks like it hanged in chrome.. but firefox is giving no such issue.. can we overcome this thing with any code if possible? –

Comment: other than the async problem, the shared code looks fine... unless we know what are the actual problem you are facing we won't be able to offer much help

Answer (score 0):

Make async:true for making the browser listen other events while running the ajax code.

Comment: I do this now and it is working but after sometime again page looks like it hanged in chrome.. but firefox is giving no such issue.. can we overcome this thing with any code if possible?

Comment: Use inspect element feature in chrome for further checking. Check with other JS files or js functions. We cant generate the bug so cant test your problem.